# Hololens Spatial Mapping Collision - Mixed Reality Toolkit

Tags: unity-game-engine, spatial, hololens

I want to put a hologram-poster in AR, on the Hololens 1, on a wall using the Mixed Reality Toolkit. But everytime I try to put a hologram onto the spatial mapping it slides right through it and vanishes behind the spatial mapping.

What did I miss?

Comment: What mrtk version do you use? Did you try the example pack? Did you try to understand what you are doing? What is your code for placing items?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you are implementing tap-to-place that enables users to move objects and place them on real-world surfaces. And your issue is that when you placing the object, it did not place on the surface as expected.

Usually, in MRTKv2, the [Solver](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html) would be a good direction to implement tap-to-place.
The [SurfaceMagnetism Solver](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html#surfacemagnetism) can cast rays to surfaces in the world, and align the object to that surface.

So, you can add SurfaceMagnetism Component to the object and create a script that has two methods, one that turns on the solver when the object is selected and one that turns off the solver while the object is deselected. When you close the solver, the object will stay in the last position.